# Is there a way to make a route entirely client-side using Next?

Tags: next.js

I am creating a web-based board game using Firebase's real-time database as the backend/engine for real-time communication. I did this a few times before using Vue, but this is the first time I tried to use Next JS (v13) as the framework of choice.

This is my current problem:

1. I create a new game, saving a new entry to the database.
2. Then, I redirect the user to a new page `games/[slug.tsx]`
3. When deployed, I'm redirected to a 404 page because Next never had the chance to generate the newly created page.

It is working when running in development mode, though.

Is there a way to make a route entirely client-side using Next? I would love to use the SSR for some of the pages in my app. I searched stackoverflow for a bit, and the suggestion of adding `dynamic()` didn't work as well.

This is the code for my GamePage:

```
import { NextPage } from "next";
import Game from "../../classes/game";
import { loadGame } from "../../api/api";
import useGame from "../../hooks/useGame";
import { useEffect } from "react";
import useCity from "../../hooks/useCity";
import CityMap from "../../components/game/board/cityMap";
import usePolice from "../../hooks/usePolice";


export async function getServerSideProps({ params }) {
    const loadedGame = await loadGame(params.slug);

    return {
        props: { loadedGame },
    };
}

const GamePage: NextPage<{ loadedGame: Game }> = ({ loadedGame }) => {

    const { game, gameActions } = useGame();
    useEffect(() => {
        if (!game) {
            gameActions.loadSavedGame(loadedGame);
        }
    }, [game, gameActions, loadedGame]);

    const { city } = useCity(loadedGame.room);
    const { police, policeActions } = usePolice(loadedGame.room);

    return (
        <CityMap city={city} police={police} policeActions={policeActions} />
    )
};

export default GamePage;
```

UPDATE: I am using getServerSideProps now, but I still see the same error. :(